# Ask root permission in a program

Tags: python, sudo, quickly

I wanted to make a program (with quickly) that edits some root files.

My question:
How can i ask for root permission (after a button is clicked) to execute a command (just like the software center does)?
I want it to be universal. For both gnome and kde

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot has changed since I asked this question in 2012. These days, `pkexec` is the preferred way to run things as root, as many desktop environments will implement their own frontend (polkit agent) for it, meaning you won't have to bother with checking for different environments. Additionally, `gksudo` and `kdesudo` have been deprecated.

Since python 3.5, the proper way to do this would be:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(["pkexec", "<command>", "<arg1>", "<arg2>"])
```

Answer (score 2):

Such a popup would come up if you execute

Gnome:

```
system("gksudo <command>");
```

KDE:

```
system("kdesudo <command>");
```

Comment: gksudo update-alternatives --remove-all java throws me an error. btw, i need something that also works with kde

Comment: This is valuable information and should be added to your original question.

Comment: here you go @cauon ;) It's up to mid_kid to create a variable for the gksudo/kdesudo difference.